# chef can't create cron

Tags: cron, chef-infra

I tried the simplest example given by http://docs.opscode.com/resource_cron.html#examples

```
    cron "name_of_cron_entry" do
        hour "8"
        weekday "6"
        mailto "admin@opscode.com"
        action :create
    end
```

I use knife ssh to make the recipe run on a chef client, and the client gives error:

```
Error executing action create on resource cron[name_of_cron_entry]
Error updating state of name_of_cron_entry, exit: 1
```

has anyone met the same problem before? Any solutions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I stumbled into this same problem and found that the example I was using had newlines in it.  The problem was that the cron provider runs `crontab -u user -` and pipes **STDIN** to the process. It appears that it doesn't accept newlines well for whatever reason.

In `/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.0/lib/chef/provider/cron.rb`, I found this:

```
status = popen4("crontab -u #{@new_resource.user} -", :waitlast => true) do |pid, stdin, stdout, stderr|
  stdin.write crontab
    end
    if status.exitstatus > 0
      raise Chef::Exceptions::Cron, "Error updating state of #{@new_resource.name}, exit: #{status.exitstatus}"
    end
```

Strangely enough, running your example seems to work for me, and creates an empty crontab entry for root:

```
root@chef-test-01:~# crontab -l
# Chef Name: name_of_cron_entry
MAILTO=admin@opscode.com
* 8 * * 6
```

This suggests to me that you are using a different version of the chef gem & cron provider.

So, depending on the version of the chef gem you are using, it could be [this bug](http://tickets.opscode.com/browse/COOK-1829)

For reference, the example that didn't work for me was based on this one:

```
cron "cookbooks_report" do
  action node.tags.include?('cookbooks-report') ? :create : :delete
  minute "0"
  hour "0"
  weekday "1"
  user "opscode"
  mailto "nharvey@opscode.com"
  home "/srv/opscode-community-site/shared/system"
  command %Q{
    cd /srv/opscode-community-site/current &&
    env RUBYLIB="/srv/opscode-community-site/current/lib"
    RAILS_ASSET_ID=`git rev-parse HEAD` RAILS_ENV="#{rails_env}"
    bundle exec rake cookbooks_report
  }
end
```

The command I was running was:

```
  command %Q{
    cd /path/to/src/my-project &&
    bundle exec my_script.rb
  }
```

There were 2 fixes that worked for me:

1. Use `command 'cd /path/to/src/my-project && bundle exec my_script.rb'`
2. Change from `cron` provider to `cron_d` provider from the [cron cookbook](http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/cron)

**Note:** I don't think the documentation for either provider in chef is correct however... [newlines are not supported in the crontab format](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/handbook/configtuning-cron.html#configtuning-cron) unless they are escaped with a backslash `\`.  In my testing with the second fix above, the resulting crontab was not valid and had newlines between commands that were not escaped.

Comment: this recipe tries to modify the cron for a user called 'opscode' which, I believe, is missing at your environment

Comment: @akiva: I copied the example from [Chef documentation](https://docs.chef.io/resource_cron.html), `user "opscode"` is what they had set as an example.  They have since changed this example to `user "getchef"`... When I tested it I obviously changed it to suit a user that existed for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran in to the same error from chef:

"Error updating state of name_of_cron_entry, exit: 1"

But in my case, the issue was a bad day-of-month value from a conditional expression. If newline-in-command isn't your issue, make sure the rest of your cron parameters fit the requirements:

- minutes: 0-59
- hours: 0-23
- day-of-month: 1-31
- month: 1-12 or JAN-DEC
- day-of-week: 0-6 or SUN-SAT
- year: 1970-2099

Answer (score 0):

Another reason for this error could be that the command you're trying to add to the crontab might be too long.

The maximum length for a cron command is 999 characters, see [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/546342/crontab-maximum-command-length).

Answer (score -1):

the [documentation](https://docs.chef.io/resource_cron.html) states that when a user is not explicitly specified chef tries to modify the root's cron. this, obviously, fails.

possible fixes:
1. specify a user in your recipe
2. run chef-apply as root (discouraged)

Comment: `chef-apply` is out of scope here, it's supposed to be used for test/one shot changes on a workstation, not for management. And chef-client is supposed to be run as root, so it is absolutely not discouraged. (And FWIW, the default is root because chef is supposed to be run as root). (Late comment sorry, but though it worth saying it)